# FFmpeg `h264_v4l2m2m` codec causing "non-existing PPS 0 referenced" error with segment muxer

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-conversion

I aim to create a "clipping" program similar to how OBS works with its replay buffer feature. I found a reference [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373148) on how to recreate that on FFmpeg using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i input -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_wrap 6 -segment_list list.m3u8 -segment_list_size 6 seg%d.ts`

Afterward, you can use either `ffmpeg -i list.m3u8 -c copy video.mp4` or `ffplay list.m3u8` to play the footage.

My issue occurs when using a time frame above the replay buffer frame (in the scenario above it would be above 24s). FFmpeg in theory should be able to capture any rolling 4 - 24 second frame. When running `ffplay list.m3u8` I run into a mass of FFmpeg errors as below:

```bash
[h264 @ 0x7f5c1c4610] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f5c1c4610] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f5c1c4610] no frame
```

I believe what's happening is that when the end of the 24-second window is reached, and the original first segment is deleted, the SDP (and the SPS and PPS) data are all deleted, as they are only located in that first segment. Therefore the rest of the segments created from that point onwards have no reference and cannot be encoded/decoded.

Here's some information about the full command I run, along with the FFmpeg version I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)" -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -pix_fmt yuv420p -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_wrap 6 -segment_list ~/Videos/FFmpeg/list.m3u8 -segment_list_size 6 ~/Videos/FFmpeg/seg%d.ts
ffmpeg version 240d82f Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm -latomic' --arch=arm64 --enable-gmp --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libssh --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libzimg --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --target-os=linux --enable-pthreads --enable-openssl --enable-hardcoded-tables
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
```

I'm running FFmpeg on a Raspberry Pi 4B 2GB with a 64-bit version of Raspberry Pi OS. Let me know if you have any additional questions, I'd really appreciate the help so thank you in advance!

UPDATE: I found out that the "issue" has to do with the hardware encoding codec of the RPi, `h264_v4l2m2m`. When using a codec like `libx264`, the issue does not appear. The reason I'm using `h264_v4l2m2m` in the first place is because I wanted to have the capacity for multiple cameras, which doesn't work well without hardware encoding.

Using `libx264` caused no issues and allowed me to use the segment muxer as normal. I don't know what's different between the two besides the hardware/software encoding. Hopefully someone out there is familiar with the difference or can help with fixing the issue.

Comment: Do you think the issue is related to Raspberry Pi? I don't have the a Pi for testing. Try creating MKV files, instead of TS. For testing, try grabbing the desktop: `ffmpeg -video_size 640x480 -framerate 5 -f x11grab -i :0.0+100,200 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f segment -segment_time 4 -segment_wrap 6 -segment_list list.txt -segment_list_type ffconcat -segment_list_size 6 seg%d.mkv`, press `q` to end recording, then `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mkv`

Comment: @Rotem Unfortunately, MKV's brought up the same issues as above. I tried using the `libx264` codec that you used, instead of `h264_v4l2m2m`, and the segment muxer worked properly with TS files.

I was hoping the issue wouldn't be related to the Raspberry Pi. The `h264_v4l2m4m` codec is the only way to get hardware encoding working on a 64-bit version of RPi OS. Without it, FFmpeg can't handle multiple (2 or more) cameras well; the framerate gets bad.

Using software encoding is a "solution", but it isn't very viable as I'm trying to set up multiple cameras with this setup. Thoughts?

Comment: Try adding bitstream filter: `-bsf:v dump_extra`, you may also use FFprobe for checking if the first frame of each segment is a key frame. I don't know if `h264_v4l2m2m` codec ignores `-force_key_frames`. For testing, add `-g 1` after `h264_v4l2m2m`.

Comment: @Rotem I tried adding both of those, including testing using FFprobe. I ran a command to check the timestamp of the key frames in `list.m3u8`, and I got a wall of non-existing PPS 0` errors, along with a couple of timestamps at the end. I checked the individual segments to make sure they each had key frames, and they did. They also had a bunch of PPS errors as well.